# Contradiction vs Inconsistency

Tags: logic

Patrick Hurley.  [*A Concise Introduction to Logic* (2014 12 ed)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1285196546). pp 346-348.

Can someone please distinguish contradictory vs. inconsistent statements more markedly and intuitively than the pages below? Please explain like I'm 5.

I see that inconsistency permits 2 statements to share the same Truth Value (F as marked by my green arrow below), but not contradictions.

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a homework forum

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda This isn't homework.

Comment: Contradictory has a specific attributes: it expresses a relationship between 2 or more  propositions where one MUST BE TRUE as well as one MUST BE FALSE. Notice the MUST BE in the descrription. You can't have any other combination other than one true & one false. That is no two true propositions & no two false propositions. The other combinations have specific names. See Aristotle's square of Opposition for those names. Inconsistencies may be contradictory propositions BUT NOT NECESSARILY contradictory.  Contradictory is one type of many types of inconsistent propositions --not the only type.

Comment: No intuition at all... It is only a pair of definitions (quite idiosyncratic).

Comment: Your image is unreadable. Your question needs to be understandable by itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this usage, two statements are *contradictory* if they are **exact opposites**: whenever one is true the other is false, and vice versa. By contrast, *inconsistency* merely demands that they **can't both be true** at the same time - while allowing them to both be *false* at the same time. So for example, A and ~A are contradictory, but A&B and ~A&B are merely inconsistent (if B is false, then *neither* statement is true). Clearly any contradictory pair of sentences is also inconsistent, but the converse fails.

(It should be noted that this usage isn't really standard, and in fact I've probably seen "contradictory" used as a synonym for "inconsistent" more frequently than not.)

Comment: I'm curious about the downvotes - this precisely explains the usage of the terms in the linked text. What's the objection, exactly?

Comment: Thanks. I didn't downvote.